# Install pattern.nlp in R

Tags: python, r

To perform a polarity analysis on Dutch text, in R, I tried to install the Pattern.nlp package (source: https://github.com/bnosac/pattern.nlp).

Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work correctly, while the READMEs does not provide the needed assistance. Could anyone help me identify where I did something wrong?

I followed the following steps to install Pattern:

(1) I installed Python 2.7.13 (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713/) on the path `C:\Python27`

(2) I downloaded Pattern-master.zip file from https://github.com/clips/pattern.

(3) I unpacked the pattern-master.zip file and put it in the location `C:\Users\...\Desktop`

(4) Then, according to the Readme, I opened the command prompt and executed;

```
cd pattern-3.6
python setup.py install
```

This led to the message "the system cannot find the path specified".

(5) So I tried `cd C:\Users\...\Desktop\pattern-master\pattern` and then `python setup.py install`, which led to the error stating that "Python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operational program or batch file".

(6) Thus, I copied the file `C:\Users\...\Desktop\pattern-master\pattern` to `C:\python27\Lib\site-packages`. As the README indicates, this should make Python aware of the module.

Did I make a mistake here?

Next step, install Pattern.nlp:

(1) Open R version 3.5.0

(2) `library(devtools)`

(3) `devtools::install_github("bnosac/pattern.nlp", args = "--no-multiarch", force = TRUE)`

This let to the following output:

```
Downloading GitHub repo bnosac/pattern.nlp@master
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.

   checking for file 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqgGXkh\remotes1e7c7f182b8d\bnosac-pattern.nlp-91a459f/DESCRIPTION' ...

   checking for file 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqgGXkh\remotes1e7c7f182b8d\bnosac-pattern.nlp-91a459f/DESCRIPTION' ... 

√  checking for file 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqgGXkh\remotes1e7c7f182b8d\bnosac-pattern.nlp-91a459f/DESCRIPTION' (616ms)

-  preparing 'pattern.nlp':
   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...

   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 

√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information

 -  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts

-  checking for empty or unneeded directories

-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added

-  building 'pattern.nlp_1.0.tar.gz


Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: failed to lock directory 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.5' for modifying
Try removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.5/00LOCK-pattern.nlp'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqgGXkh/file1e7c33eb40ba/pattern.nlp_1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
```

(4) Executed `library("pattern.nlp")`
This let to:

```
Error in find_python_cmd(minimum_version = minimum_version, maximum_version = maximum_version,  : 
  Couldn't find a sufficient Python binary. If you haven't installed the Python dependency yet please do so. If you have but it isn't on the system path (as is default on Windows) please add it to path or set options('python_cmd'='/path/to/binary')  or set the PYTHON, PYTHON2, or PYTHON3 environmental variables.   Python must have access to the modules: pattern.db
```

If I installed Pattern correctly, what did I do wrong while installing Pattern.nlp? The error would indicate that I need to set the PYTHON environmental variables; unfortunately I do not know how.

(5) Following the README, I also executed `findpython::can_find_python_cmd`. This generated the following:

```
function (minimum_version = NULL, maximum_version = NULL, required_modules = NULL, 
    error_message = NULL, silent = FALSE) 
{
    python_cmd <- try(find_python_cmd(minimum_version = minimum_version, 
        maximum_version = maximum_version, required_modules = required_modules, 
        error_message = error_message), silent = silent)
    if (inherits(python_cmd, "try-error")) {
        r <- FALSE
    }
    else {
        r <- TRUE
        attr(r, "python_cmd") <- python_cmd
    }
    r
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000553c0d28>
<environment: namespace:findpython>
```

Thanks in advance for providing assistance! I am trying to figure this out for over one day now and it starts to become really frustrating.

Comment: The warning says you need to install Rtools. Try `install.packages("Rtools")` or check out the link they gave http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: I tried that, but it gave the error `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)` (same when using "Rtools35"). 

So, I installed the .exe from the link you provided. However, I still was not able to use `install.packages` to load it into R. As a consequence, the error maintained.

Do you believe that installing R 3.3 would solve the problem?

Comment: You downloaded `Rtools35.exe`? That should work for R >= 3.3 (so you don't need to go to an earlier version of R). After installing it, you don't need to do `install.packages`, you should use `library(Rtools)` to load the package.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the Rtools35.exe, unfortunately `library(Rtools)` let to the error `Error in library(Rtools) : there is no package called ‘Rtools’`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in the answer, my full troubleshooting procedure is documented here: https://github.com/bnosac/pattern.nlp/issues/8

In short: I needed to use Pattern2.6 instead of 3.6 and I needed to use `devtools::install_github("bnosac/pattern.nlp", INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")`.